# PostgreSQL calling another function

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL function with the following signature..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetResults (Weight numeric, documents boolean, country_code text) 
RETURNS TABLE (
itemcode varchar(20)
,kilocode varchar(20)
) AS $$
DECLARE 
    .....
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Now I need to create another function and use the results from the above function (itemcode, kilocode). This is how I tried to use the function above

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetProductList(
    country_code text,
    maxdim numeric,
    weight numeric,
    volume numeric,
    promo_code character varying,
    documents boolean)
 RETURNS TABLE(code varchar (20)
, cms_code varchar (20)
, service_code varchar (20)
, service_name varchar (10)
, service_group varchar (1000)
, signature_required boolean
, service_promo_code varchar (10)) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $$
DECLARE
    var_pg_rec record;
    sqlToExecute varchar(1000);
    val_true boolean := 't';
BEGIN

.....

FOR var_pg_rec IN EXECUTE sqlToExecute USING Weight, country_code, val_true
LOOP
    Select itemcode , kilocode from GetResults (Weight, documents, country_code);
    code := var_pg_rec.ProductGroupName || itemcode;
    cms_code := var_pg_rec.ProductGroupName || kilocode;
    service_code := 'DummyService';
    service_name := 'Dummy Service 10.0kg';
    service_group := 'Dummy Service 10.0kg';
    signature_required := false;
    service_promo_code := 'dummyPro';
    RETURN NEXT;
END LOOP;
```

END $$;

when I do the above, I get the following error

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT … FROM GetResult(…) result`? Please show us how you tried calling it, and what problems you did face (like error messages).

Answer (score 0):

Your statement "Select itemcode , kilocode ..." does not do anything with the selected values. So Postgres doesn't know at that point that you intend on using them later. To so tell Postgres this fact you need to provide a *location* to save the results. You accomplish this via the looping through the result set of the GetResults function (functions that return tables can return multiple rows) or changing to "Select ... into ..." format in the function. Below is a demonstration of each. Since you didn't post your full routine I used some local routines I have to generate random data elements; those routines all begin SOQ. I've further commented where I changed your routines;

Data Generation Routines:

```
create or replace function soq.random_int(
    l integer,
    h integer)
  returns integer 
 language sql strict
 as $$
    select floor(random() * (h-l+1) + l)::integer;
$$;


create or replace function soq.random_keyboard_char()
  returns text
language sql
as $$
    with keyboard_char as 
       ( select array[ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '_', '$', '#'
                     , 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
                     , 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'] ca
       ) 
     select ca[soq.random_int(1,array_length(ca,1))]::text from keyboard_char; 
$$;                    

create or replace function soq.random_text(max_length_in integer) 
  returns text  
language sql strict
as $$
   with recursive t(n,cl) as 
       ( select 1, soq.random_keyboard_char()
         union all 
         select t.n+1, concat(t.cl,soq.random_keyboard_char())
           from t 
          where n<=max_length_in
       )
  select cl from t where n = max_length_in;
$$;
```

With that out of the way, now your routines. First assuming GetResuts returns multiple rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetResults (Weight numeric, documents boolean, country_code text) 
RETURNS TABLE (
itemcode varchar(20)
,kilocode varchar(20)
) 
AS $$
declare 
    lcnt integer :=1;
begin
    if documents 
    then 
        lcnt = weight::integer; 
    end if; 

    while lcnt > 0
    loop 
        select soq.random_text(20),soq.random_text(20) into itemcode,kilocode;
        return next;
    end loop;

    return; 
END;  $$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetProductList(
    country_code text,
    maxdim numeric,
    weight numeric,
    volume numeric,
    promo_code character varying,
    documents boolean)
 RETURNS TABLE(code varchar (20)
, cms_code varchar (20)
, service_code varchar (20)
, service_name varchar (10)
, service_group varchar (1000)
, signature_required boolean
, service_promo_code varchar (10)) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $$
DECLARE
    var_pg_rec record;
    sqlToExecute varchar(1000);
    val_true boolean := 't';

    results record;                                                                          -- added
BEGIN

sqlToExecute = $stmt$                                                                        -- added  
                with  gl as (select * from generate_series (1, coalesce($1::integer,1) ))    -- added
                Select 'Group_' || row_number() over()  || '::' as ProductGroupName          -- added
                          ,  $2                                                              -- added
                          ,  $3                                                              -- added
                       from gl ;                                                             -- added
               $stmt$;                                                                       -- added
--.....                                                                                      -- commented

FOR var_pg_rec IN EXECUTE sqlToExecute USING Weight, country_code, val_true
LOOP
    for results in ( select * from GetResults (Weight, documents, country_code) )        -- changed 
    loop                                                                                 -- added
        code := var_pg_rec.ProductGroupName || results.itemcode;                         -- changed
        cms_code := var_pg_rec.ProductGroupName || results.kilocode;                     -- changed 
        service_name := 'Dummy Service 10.0kg';
        service_group := 'Dummy Service 10.0kg';
        signature_required := false;
        service_promo_code := 'dummyPro';
        RETURN NEXT;
    end loop;                                                                             -- added 
END LOOP;
return ;                                                                                  -- added
end; 
$$ ;
```

Finally, the alternative for GetProductList function if you know the GetProducts function always returns at lost 1 row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetProductList(
    country_code text,
    maxdim numeric,
    weight numeric,
    volume numeric,
    promo_code character varying,
    documents boolean)
 RETURNS TABLE(code varchar (20)
, cms_code varchar (20)
, service_code varchar (20)
, service_name varchar (10)
, service_group varchar (1000)
, signature_required boolean
, service_promo_code varchar (10)) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $$
DECLARE
    var_pg_rec record;
    sqlToExecute varchar(1000);
    val_true boolean := 't';

    results record;  
    l_itemcode text;
    l_kilocode  text;                                                                        -- added
BEGIN

sqlToExecute = $stmt$                                                                        -- added  
                with  gl as (select * from generate_series (1, coalesce($1::integer,1) ))    -- added
                Select 'Group_' || row_number() over()  || '::' as ProductGroupName          -- added
                          ,  $2                                                              -- added
                          ,  $3                                                              -- added
                       from gl ;                                                             -- added
               $stmt$;                                                                       -- added
--.....                                                                                      -- commented

    FOR var_pg_rec IN EXECUTE sqlToExecute USING Weight, country_code, val_true
    LOOP
        select itemcode,kilocode                                                            -- changed  
          into l_itemcode, l_kilocode                                                       -- changed 
          from GetResults (Weight, documents, country_code);                                -- changed 

        code := var_pg_rec.ProductGroupName || l_itemcode;                                  -- changed
        cms_code := var_pg_rec.ProductGroupName || l_kilocode;                              -- changed 
        service_name := 'Dummy Service 10.0kg';
        service_group := 'Dummy Service 10.0kg';
        signature_required := false;
        service_promo_code := 'dummyPro';
        RETURN NEXT;                                                                         -- added 
    END LOOP;
    return ;                                                                                 -- added
end; 
$$ ;
```

Take note of how each version handles the data returned from GetResults function.